# Web Scraping - printing values together - Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, printing, attributeerror

So I'm trying to scrape CS:GO skins, I'm trying to return: Skin name, Price and collection - in that order.

This is one of many ways I have tried it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()

def webscrape():

    url = "https://csgostash.com/weapon/AWP"
    res = requests.get(url = url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

    titles = soup.find_all('div', class_="well result-box nomargin")
    prices = soup.find_all('div', class_="price")
    collection = soup.find_all('div', class_="collection")

    for title in titles:
        title = title.find('a')
        if title:
            title = title.text

    for price in prices:
        price = price.find('p')
        if price:
            price = price.text

    for cases in collection:
        cases = cases.find('p')
        if price:
            cases = cases.text
    print(title.text, price.text, collection.text)

webscrape()
```

This returns:

```
    print(title.text, price.text, collection.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I want it to return the three values in order.
E.G. 
Containment Breach '\n'
A$40.57 -A$271.90'\n'
Shattered Web Case

and so on. Some of the skins have 2 Price sets, and I want both price sets to print out.

I have gotten it working more to show what I'm struggling with

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()

def webscrape():

    url = "https://csgostash.com/weapon/AWP"
    res = requests.get(url = url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    names = " "
    price = " "
    cases = " "
    titles = soup.find_all('div', class_="well result-box nomargin")
    prices = soup.find_all('div', class_="price")
    collection = soup.find_all('div', class_="collection")

    for name in titles:
        a_field = name.find('a')
        if a_field:
            names = a_field.text + '\n' + names

    for money in prices:
        p_field = money.find('p')
        if p_field:
            price = p_field.text + '\n' + price

    for case in collection:
        case_field = case.find('p')
        if case_field:
            cases = case_field.text + '\n' + cases
    print(names, price, cases)

webscrape()
```

This prints all the information I am looking for on the webpage but i want the information grouped together, like i want the prices and the collection for the skin to print under the name of the skin. Right now it prints all the name, then all the prices, then all the collections.

Comment: Scope of `title` is only inside that `for` loop.

Comment: You have to declare your variables outside the loops. When you loop over your titles, price, and cases, you check if it found an element. When you print, you don't check if the element was found. So if it did not find an element, you will still try to access the text attribute of a None object

Comment: @narendra-choudhary: That is incorrect; the given run-time error shows otherwise.  Please revisit the Python scoping rules.

Comment: @Prune you are correct. `title` will be available outside loop. Bit of mind-fade on my part. Little Python/Java mixup there!

Comment: Do you have a specific question? What do you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 0):

```
titles = soup.find_all('div', class_="well result-box nomargin")

for title in titles:
    title = title.find('a')
    if title:
        title = title.text
```

You are overwriting data on each iteration of the loop; I'm not at all clear on what you *think* you're doing.  The only way I see this working is if your final iteration finds what you want ... in which case `title` exits as the last `text` value you found.

At the end, you then try to take the `.text` attribute of *that*.  This will almost certainly fail in some undesirable way.

To get the error you see, the last item in `titles` does contain 'a', *and* has a `text` attribute of `None`; later, when you try to extract an attribute of `None`, you get the indicated error.

Instead, try

```
titles = soup.find_all('div', class_="well result-box nomargin")

for title in titles:
    a_field = title.find('a')
    if a_field:
        break
```

*This* gets you out of the search loop as soon as find the desired attribute.